# Send Message to Telegram Bot Without Open Telegram Apps

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

usually if we want to chat or send command to Telegram Bot, we just texting the bot from Telegram apps (desktop, web, or smartphone). Is there any way texting the bot without open Telegram apps??
I've read many website and thread in stackoverflow, but no clue..

Comment: You can use Telegram API to build your app. https://core.telegram.org/

Answer (score 3):

How about GET request from browser? just paste it into your adress bar and press enter :

https://api.telegram.org/bot**YOUR_BOT_API**/sendMessage?chat_id=**SOME_CHAT_ID**&text=hi

replace YOUR_BOT_API with your bot token

replace SOME_CHAT_ID with some chat_id (user_id, if u have no idea what chat_id is, just send the text message to the @userinfobot and the bot shows the user_id from the post you've send to the bot)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `token` of the bot, you can directly call the [Telegram Bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api) using your browser or any other program that allows you to perform requests on the web. But you would not be able to see what the bot answers since you can not access the messages written by the bot via the API.

If you want to quickly access a bot without firing up Telegram Desktop or any other official app I recommend you to have a look into [telegram-cli](https://github.com/vysheng/tg). Though it might be a little outdated I think you can still use it. You can execute telegram-cli with command options (e.g. sending a command to a bot) for quick access from the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start the bot without opening Telegram, you could use an automated client. For example, you can use PHP with [MadelineProto](https://github.com/danog/madelineproto)